# Эффективные методы по скорости получения элементов из коллекции - C#

Tags: c#, оптимизация, коллекции

Необходимо реализовать эффективный по скорости метод получения элементов из коллекции по Id или Name. В настоящий момент реализовал только через `foreach`, но это не эффективно.

```
public class DoubleKeyDictionary<Id, Name, Value> : Enumerable<KeyValuePair<Tuple<Id, Name>, Value>>
{
     private Dictionary<Tuple<Id, Name>, Value> innerDictionary = new Dictionary<Tuple<Id, Name>, Value>();
     //код
     //эффективный по скорости метод получения элементов из коллекции
}
```

Comment: Правка (обе правки) от Dmitry действительно улучшали читабельность. не стоило их отклонять.

Comment: Каков размер коллекции? Если очень большой, то, может, использовать базу данных, хранящуюся в памяти? Например, Sqlite in memory.

Comment: нет, базу данных не нужно использовать

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Самый быстрый способ в вашем случае - хранить два отдельных словаря-индекса `Dictionary<Id, Value>` для поиска по Id и `Dictionary<Name, Value>` для поиска по Name.

Ваш innerDictionary сейчас хранит данные в следующем виде (если упрощенно):
- все пары ключ/значение разделены на кучки по hashcode от ключа - buckets.
- внутри каждго bucket-а данные лежат в виде связного списка.

Хэшкод у `Tuple<ID, Name>` зависит от обоих значений. Т.е. ключи с одинаковым Id, но разным Name будут имет разный хэшкод. Соответственно, будут лежать в разных бакетах, причем зная только Id вы все равно не сможете узнать все бакеты, которых лежат значения с ключами с этим Id. Т.е. вам придется делать полный перебор.

Comment: PashaPash: идея хорошая, только я получаю исключение при добавлении элемента "'элемент с таким ключом уже был добавлен" т.к. ключ у меня составной.

Comment: @Vladimir у вас могут быть записи с одинаковым ID или с одинаковым Name? Ну тогда заведите `Dictionary<Id, List<Value>>`

Comment: в коллекции ключ составной. Т.е. `myCollection.myMethodadd(1,"A","Hello")`  `myCollection.myMethodadd(1,"B","World")`  - исключение!!!

Comment: Ну вот я вам и предлагаю (комментом выше!) завести для поиска по Id отдельный `Dictionary<int, List<string>>` в котором по ключу 1 будет лежать список из всех значений с ID 1 - т.е. запись в этом "индексе" будет вида `{ 1, new List<string>{ "Hello", "World" } }`. Ну и, соответственно, при поиске по ID = 1 вы будете возвращать эти два значения.

Comment: Спасибо огромное, решено!!!

Answer (score 0):

В данном случае нужно создать объект ключа в виде класса или структуры и переопределить методы GetHashCode и Equals.

Эффективность выборки будет зависит от того, какой алгоритм вы используете в GetHashCode. [Здесь](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ruericlippert/943) перевод статьи одного из гуру по данному случаю.